# regarding the usage of tf.tile and tf.pack

Tags: tensorflow

I saw a program including the following two lines of codes

```
exponential_map = tf.exp(output_map)
sum_exp = tf.reduce_sum(exponential_map, 3, keep_dims=True)
tensor_sum_exp = tf.tile(sum_exp, tf.pack([1, 1, 1, tf.shape(output)[3]]))
```

The `output_map` is of shape `(1,255,255,2)`. I can see `sum_exp` generally add the two channels for the `exponential_map` into one. So `sum_exp` should be of shape `(1,255,255,1)`. But I am confused about what does `tensor_sum_exp = tf.tile(sum_exp, tf.pack([1, 1, 1, tf.shape(output)[3]]))` aim to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It makes multiple copies of the image along dimension 3.

It looks up the (dynaminc) number of output channels:

```
outchannels = tf.shape(output)[3]
```

Then it builds a tensor containing the number of multiples along each dimension:

```
multiples = tf.pack([1, 1, 1, outchanels])
```

And makes that many copies:

```
tensor_sum_exp = tf.tile(sum_exp, multiples)
```

If for example, you know `outchannels` is always `n`, (check `sum_exp.get_shape()`), you could also:

```
tensor_sum_exp = tf.concat(3,[sum_exp]*n)
```

Comment: so generally it just make three copies of the original image. For example, if the original one is 255*255*1, then it will generate 255*255*3. Is that right?